# Remove php extension from files in a specific folder without affecting some subfolders

Tags: php, .htaccess, directory, subdirectory

Please I’m working on a project and the way I usually arrange my files and folders are such that all my php scripts are usually in a folder call ‘lib’ but each time I use htaccess to remove the .php extension, it tends to affect those scripts from running, also the main pages are usually in the root folder and I would want to remove their .php extension

Comment: You can use mod_rewrite in a Directory tag.

Comment: Please @JoelCrypto can you show me an example? I'm a bit confused thanks

Answer (score 0):

Create a .htaccess in lib directory and write the following code in the file :

```
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.php$ $1
```

And in httpd write the following :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule "^([^\.]+)$" "$1.php" [PT]
```

Comment: Ok, thanks I’ll try it out and let you know

Comment: It gave me an error, page not found

Comment: On Which pages?

Comment: all pages, I just copied and pasted your code didn't modify anything and it says object not found

Comment: I have changed my code. This is working for me.

Comment: So you mean I should configure my localhost server with that httpd code?

Comment: The second one yes